Is it possible to include userecordtypecheck=1 and defaultFieldValues in the same URL?
I'm currently set up using userecordtypecheck=1 because of multiple record types. I'm looking for a way to further this by using the defaultFieldValues= but these do not seem to work together. Am I missing something? Any insight greatly appreciated.
Thank you for any input.
Bob Moalli (MEDITECH)

Bottom of this post by ISV Partner advocate Amit Chaudry discusses limitations and options. I suggest multiple buttons, one per recordtype
